# How to change the default generic type for AddDefaultIdentity in Asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I created a `ApplicationUser` class that inherits `IdentityUser`, then in the `StartUp` class, I changed the `services.AddDefaultIdentiy` generic type from `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser` so I can get the service for `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` instead of `UserManager<IdentityUser>` .

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

I got this error

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.

And I can't add two default identity to the service I need help on how to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that if you change `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser` in Views\Shared_LoginPartial.cshtml is injected

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```